# Add a batch script to windows right click menu, to run applications with psexec tool

Tags: windows-registry, cmd.exe

I want to make a batch-script that runs a selected application with PsExec.exe tool.
And I want to add this option to the right-click menu. Like the "Run As Administrator" menu on windows 7.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't you mean PsExec.exe?

Comment: This will show you the basic idea: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista but it's going to take some effort to get this to actually work the way you are wanting it to.

Answer (score 3):

That is quite an easy thing to do but here are some basics first:

All your context menu items that deal individual files or up to 15 files selected can be found here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
```

folder related actions are broken up into 2 categories: actions available when you right click background and actions when you right click a folder. And they can be found here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
```

Drives have their own keys here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell
```

The structure of context menu commands will be as follows

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\(*,Directory or Drive)\shell\(Command's Main Key)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\(*,Directory or Drive)\shell\(Command's Main Key)\command <=this will store the executed command when when the context menu item related to this key is selected
```

The Command entry in the context menu will have the same name as the main key unless you specify differently by creating a String Value called MUIverb under the main key. Eg. You can make a String Value called MUIverb and set it value as New Name ("MUIverb"="New Name").

A command that will be located in the extended shift when it has a String Value called Extended under the main key. You want it to be in the main shell context menu, delete the "Extended" String Value entry. You want to transfer something to the extended menu, just put "Extended" in it's main key. You can also specify an icon for the menu entry by putting another String Value in the same key. Eg: "Icon"="C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll,133" or "Icon"="C:\Pictures\Icons\SomeRandomIcon.ico".